# Oracle SQL : How to delete Duplicate Rows

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, duplicates, subquery, sql-delete

Implemented removal of duplicate rows as per https://www.oracletutorial.com/advanced-oracle-sql/how-to-delete-duplicate-records-in-oracle/.

However, my situation needs further work. Let's assume that my Table looks like this :

```
CREATE TABLE fruits
(
    fruit_id   NUMBER generated BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    fruit_name VARCHAR2(100),
    color      VARCHAR2(20),
    status     varchar2(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (fruit_id)
);

INSERT  INTO fruits(fruit_name, color, status) VALUES ('Apple', 'Red', 'INITIAL');
INSERT  INTO fruits(fruit_name, color, status)  VALUES ('Apple', 'Red', 'INITIAL');
INSERT  INTO fruits(fruit_name, color, status) VALUES ('Orange', 'Orange', 'COMPLETE');
INSERT  INTO fruits(fruit_name, color, status) VALUES ('Orange', 'Orange', 'INITIAL');
INSERT  INTO fruits(fruit_name, color, status) VALUES ('Orange', 'Orange', 'INITIAL');
INSERT  INTO fruits(fruit_name, color, status) VALUES ('Banana', 'Yellow', 'INITIAL');
INSERT  INTO fruits(fruit_name, color, status) VALUES ('Banana', 'Green', 'INITIAL');

DELETE
FROM fruits
WHERE fruit_id NOT IN
      (
          SELECT MAX(fruit_id)
          FROM fruits
          GROUP BY fruit_name,
                   color
      )
  AND STATUS = 'INITIAL';
```

After deleting the duplicates like above, I still find that one of the duplicate rows(fruit_id =5) still remains.

```
select * from fruits;

2,Apple,Red,INITIAL
3,Orange,Orange,COMPLETE
5,Orange,Orange,INITIAL
6,Banana,Yellow,INITIAL
7,Banana,Green,INITIAL
```

I would like to delete all duplicate rows that are in 'INITIAL' state.

How should I go about it ?

**UPDATE**

Just to be sure, the logic should be : All NON-MAX records in 'INITIAL' state should be deleted. Also, if a record with 'COMPLETE' status is present, then I'd like the duplicate 'INITIAL' record to be deleted as well. In my example, I'd like record with fruit_id = 5(with STATE='INITIAL') to be deleted since there's another record with fruit_id =3(with STATE='COMPLETE') which has the same value of "orange", "orange" but with 'COMPLETE' value.

Comment: In your scenario can there be more than one `Completed` with same `fruit_name`and `color`?

Comment: I think the record with `fruit_id = 2` should be deleted instead of the one with `fruit_id = 1` as being **non-max** for own group of `fruit_name` and `color`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a correlated subquery. I think the logic you want is:

```
delete from fruits f
where status = 'INITIAL' and exists(
    select 1 
    from fruits f1 
    where 
        f1.fruit_name = f.fruit_name 
        and f1.color = f.color
        and (
            (f1.status = 'INITIAL' and f1.fruit_id > f.fruit_id)
            or (f1.status = 'COMPLETE' and f1.fruit_id <> f.fruit_id)
        )
)
```

This deletes rows whose status is initial and for which another row exists with the same name and color and either status initial and a greater id, or status complete.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f3d071793d9c109b8aeb3fc6c54056c4)**:

```
FRUIT_ID | FRUIT_NAME | COLOR  | STATUS  
-------: | :--------- | :----- | :-------
       2 | Apple      | Red    | INITIAL 
       3 | Orange     | Orange | COMPLETE
       6 | Banana     | Yellow | INITIAL 
       7 | Banana     | Green  | INITIAL
```

Comment: HI @GMB, thanks. Obviously, this is not the exact table I have in my DB. My Table has about 20 columns and about 50K records. Except fruit_id(PK), none of the columns have an index. What should I do to make your DELETE NOT take enormous amount of time ? Also, our DB is Oracle 11 and not Oracle 18c

Comment: @anjanb: an index on `(color, fruit_name, status)` *might* be useful. 50k records is not that much, so I would not really expect performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the rows you want to keep:

```
select f.*
from (select f.*,
             sum(case when status = 'COMPLETE' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by fruit_name, color) as num_complete,
             max(id) over (partition by fruit_name, color) as max_id
      from fruits f
     ) f
where status = 'COMPLETE' or
      (num_complete = 0 and id < max_id);
```

This is a good basis for doing the `delete`.  One method:

```
delete fruits f
    where not exists (select 1
                      from (select f2.*,
                                   sum(case when status = 'COMPLETE' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by fruit_name, color) as num_complete,
                                   max(id) over (partition by fruit_name, color) as max_id
                            from fruits f2
                           ) f2
                      where ( f.status = 'COMPLETE' or
                              (f.num_complete = 0 and f.id < f.max_id)
                            ) and
                            f.fruit_id = f2.fruit_id
                     );
```

If you are deleting a lot of rows in a large table, you might find it more efficient to recreate the table:

```
create table temp_fruits as
    select fruit_id, fruit_name, color, status
    from (select f.*,
                 sum(case when status = 'COMPLETE' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by fruit_name, color) as num_complete,
                 max(id) over (partition by fruit_name, color) as max_id
          from fruits f
         ) f
    where status = 'COMPLETE' or
          (num_complete = 0 and id < max_id);

truncate table fruits;

insert into fruits (fruit_id, fruit_name, color, status)
     select * from temp_fruits;
```

Note that this changes the row id as well.

I originally misunderstood, thinking you wanted to delete the `COMPLETE` record as well:

```
delete fruits f
    where exists (select 1 
                  from fruits f2
                  where f2.fruit_name = f.fruit_name and
                        f2.color = f.color and
                        f2.status = 'COMPLETE'
                 ) or
          f.id < (select max(f2.id)
                 from fruits f2
                 where f2.fruit_name = f.fruit_name and
                       f2.color = f.color
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function

```
DELETE fruits
 WHERE fruit_id IN 
     ( WITH del AS 
      (
       SELECT f.*,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER
              (PARTITION BY fruit_name, color 
                   ORDER BY CASE WHEN f.status = 'COMPLETE' THEN 0 ELSE fruit_id END) 
                      AS rn                            
         FROM fruits f
       )  
       SELECT fruit_id
         FROM del
        WHERE status = 'INITIAL'
          AND rn > 1
      )
```

where rn > 1 filters out records with non-max fruit_id values when grouped by fruit_name and color.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=664fe81bb5d74d401c0e196059bbb53d)</kbd>

Comment: Hi @Barbaros Özhan : Thanks. I tried this but modified the order in which "orange" records were inserted and now the query doesn't return what is expected. The Query retains record with fruit_id =3 which is a duplicate -- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=06caf060518d9264d40127496697eaa6. Could you fix that  ? thanks

Comment: you're welcome @anjanb . I've just edited. Seems you need conditional logic for the records with `status = 'COMPLETED'`.

Answer (score 0):

You added an additional column so the logic needs to be modified. The `NOT IN` clause looks at all fruit in any status, you should limit that to only fruit in INITIAL status

```
DELETE
FROM fruits
WHERE fruit_id NOT IN
      (
          SELECT MAX(fruit_id)
          FROM fruits WHERE status = 'INITIAL'
          GROUP BY fruit_name,
                   color
      )
AND status = 'INITIAL';
```

Comment: Hi @Koen Lostrie : That doesn't work since fruit_id = 5 is the max. I'd like all NON-MAX records to be deleted. Also, if a record with 'COMPLETE' status is present, then I'd like the 'INITIAL' record with MAX value to be deleted as well. In my example, I'd like record with fruit_id = 5 to be deleted since there's another record with fruit_id =3 which has the same value of "orange", "orange" but with 'COMPLETE' value.

Comment: still doesn't work. I didn't see any change. I didn't introduce any new column. Just clarified expectation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do the following:

```sql
DELETE
FROM fruits f
WHERE STATUS = 'INITIAL'
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM fruits
               WHERE fruit_name = f.fruit_name
                 AND color = f.color
                 AND (STATUS != f.STATUS OR fruit_id > f.fruit_id))
```

Instead of GROUPING the values you can check if another entry exists that fits better:

- The `STATUS` is no any longer 'INITIAL'
- The `FRUIT_ID` is higher

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from fruits where fruit_id not in 
(
    select  fruit_id_
    from    fruits
    match_recognize
    (
        partition by fruit_name, color
        order by fruit_id
        measures fruit_id as fruit_id_
        all rows per match 
        pattern ( ( a  {- b* -} ) | ( c {- d* -} ) )
        define  a as status = 'INITIAL', 
                b as status = a.status ,
                c as status = 'COMPLETE',
                d as status = 'INITIAL'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete duplicated rows, you can use the following statement:

DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE rowid not in
(SELECT MIN(rowid)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3);